# How to copy all content (<p><strong>) from a div and paste in a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On the website that I'm working on I have a section for staff, and each staff member has a bio: my idea is that if the user click read more a modal opens and displays the bio. What I'm trying to do is to have the `onclick` get the bio of the staff and pass that to the modal, is there a way to copy and paste all the code, including the `<p><strong>`, so that it keeps the style?

```js
function openModal(id) {
  console.log(id);
  modal.style.display = "block";
  var content = document.getElementById(id);
  modalContent.innerHTML = content.text;
  console.log(content);
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="myModal">
  <button onclick="closeModal()">&times;</button>
  <div id="modalContent"></div>
</div>
<div class="description">
  <h2>Exercitation</h2>
  <p onclick="openModal('1')">Read more...</p>
  <div id="1">
    <h2> Exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</h2>
    <hr>
    <p><strong>adipisicing elit</strong></p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="description">
  <h2>Exercitation</h2>
  <p onclick="openModal('2')">Read more...</p>
  <div id="2">
    <h2> Exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</h2>
    <hr>
    <p><strong>adipisicing elit</strong></p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well there is no `.text`, you set innerHTML, seems weird you are not using innerHTML to read the content

Comment: Since you are tag the question with jquery, can't you do this with https://api.jquery.com/html/ as far as styling is concerned, you can declare the css in a way that it works for in and out of the modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using jQuery's `html()`:

```js
function openModal(id) {
  //the div's content, HTML included
  //equivalent to Vanilla JS's innerHTML
  content = $("#" + id).html(); 
  
  console.log(content);
  
  //inset that HTML content into the div of ID 'modalContent'
  $("#modalContent").html(content);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="description">
        <h2>Exercitation</h2> 
        <p onclick="openModal('1')">Read more...</p>
        <div id="1">
            <h2> Exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</h2>
            <hr>
            <p><strong>adipisicing elit</strong></p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This answer would only apply to the first div. OP supplied two possible divs in his question.

Comment: @CarlEdwards right, but now OP can build on this to continue.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
//You get the HTML of the element with innerHTML property.
var content = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;

//I assume you have define modalContent variable somewhere else in your js file, so:
modalContent.innerHTML = content;
```

You can do this all in one line also:

`document.getElementById("modalContent").innerHTML = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the modal in your function and also grab the `content`'s `innerHTML` and assign it to your `modalContent` for this to work:

```js
function openModal(id) {
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
  var modalContent = document.getElementById('modalContent');
  console.log(id);
  modal.style.display = "block";
  var content = document.getElementById(id);
  modalContent.innerHTML = content.innerHTML;
  console.log(content);
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="myModal">
  <button onclick="closeModal()">&times;</button>
  <div id="modalContent">

  </div>
</div>

<div class="description">
  <h2>Exercitation</h2>
  <p onclick="openModal('1')">Read more...</p>
  <div id="1">
    <h2> Exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</h2>
    <hr>
    <p><strong>adipisicing elit</strong></p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="description">
  <h2>Exercitation</h2>
  <p onclick="openModal('2')">Read more...</p>
  <div id="2">
    <h2> Exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</h2>
    <hr>
    <p><strong>adipisicing elit</strong></p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the question was tagged with jQuery I propose a solution using that.

You can view it in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0gpm1hwx/2/).

I did modify your code, here's a summary of what I changed:

1. First I removed the inline `onClick` attributes and instead use jQuery's `$(element).on('click', function)`
2. Then I added classes like `.open-modal` and `.close-modal` where appropriate. With this approach you don't have to pass the ID of the element, you can just get the content nearest the button that was clicked.
3. I added a `.modal-info` class to the information container, for easier targeting.
4. Finally, I handled all of the opening/closing with jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="myModal" class="myModal">
        <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
        <div id="modalContent">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="description">
        <h2>Exercitation</h2> 
        <p class="open-modal">Read more...</p>
        <div id="1" class="modal-info">
            <h2>#1 Exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</h2>
            <hr>
            <p><strong>adipisicing elit</strong></p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="description">
        <h2>Exercitation</h2> 
        <p class="open-modal">Read more...</p>
        <div id="2" class="modal-info">
            <h2>#2 Exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</h2>
            <hr>
            <p><strong>adipisicing elit</strong></p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.open-modal').on('click', open_modal);

$('.close-modal').on('click', close_modal);

function open_modal() {

  // Modal container
  var $modal = $('#myModal');

  // Get content container
  var $modal_content = $('#modalContent');

  // Empty existing content first
  $modal_content.empty();

  // Get new content
  // $(this) is the .open-modal element that was clicked
  // I'm using jQuery siblings() to get the nearest .modal-info element
  var new_modal_content = $(this).siblings('.modal-info').html();

  // Set new content
  $modal_content.html(new_modal_content);

  // Display modal
  $modal.show();

}

function close_modal(){

    var $modal = $('#myModal');

    if($modal.is(':visible')){
        $modal.hide();
  }

}
```

**CSS:**

```
#myModal {
  display: none;
}

.modal-info {
  display: none;
}
```

It's not perfect though and could be improved. Still, I think it's easier to maintain than inline onClick attributes and what not.